# how to make a variable decrease by one everytime a loop rolls?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

this might seem very basic to you, and I think I know what is wrong with my code, I just can't seem to figure out how to fix. Basically, I am building a very simple hangman game, and I want to make the user lose a life every time he guesses a letter wrong. Here is the code:

```
import random
word_choice = ["list", "microsoft", "cars", "philosophy", "mother", "powder", "star", "baby", "elephant"]
guessed_letters = []
right_guessed_letters = []




def user_turn(c):
    lives = 10
    while True:
        guess = input("\nGuess a letter or a word: ")
        guessed_letters.append(guess)
        print ("\n")
        if lives != 0 and guess != comp_choice:
            if guess in comp_choice:
                right_guessed_letters.append(guess)
                for i in comp_choice:
                    if i in right_guessed_letters:
                        print (i, end= ' ')
                    else:
                        print ('-', end = ' ')
            else:
                lose_life(lives)
            continue
        elif guess == comp_choice:
            print ("Good job, you guessed the word correctly!")
            break
        elif  lives == 0:
            print ("You lost, your lives are all depleated...")
            break

def lose_life(l):
    l -= 1
    print (f'Wrong letter, you have {l} lives remaining')
    print (f"The letters you already guessed are {guessed_letters}")



comp_choice = random.choice(word_choice)
word = '-' * len(comp_choice)
print (f"Your word is : {word} long.")


user_turn(comp_choice)
```

Basically, my problem is that the user can only lose one life. In fact, I would like that every time lose_life is called, the user loses a life so his lives decrease by one every time, however the variable lives gets it's original value right after the function is done rolling. So every time the function is called, the user is at nine lives. Here is the output:

```
microsoft
Your word is : --------- long.

Guess a letter or a word: d


Wrong letter, you have 9 lives remaining
The letters you already guessed are ['d']

Guess a letter or a word: e


Wrong letter, you have 9 lives remaining
The letters you already guessed are ['d', 'e']

Guess a letter or a word:
```

Anyways, If you could help, it would be very appreciated!

Comment: Changing the `l` in `lose_life(l)` does not change the calling function's variable - `lives`? Integers in python are immutable, the `l -= 1` is just assigning a new value to `l` not changing original value of `l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lose_life` function is not returning anything, so all it effectively does is printing the two statements.

if you added a `return l` at the end of `lose_life` function, and change your `lose_life(lives)` in the else statement to `lives = lose_life(lives)`, it should now work.

If this seems cumbersome and you're feeling adventurous, you may consider using Classes instead:

```
class Live(object):
    def __init__(self, value=10):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
    def lose(self):
        self.value -= 1
        print(f'Wrong letter, you have {self.value} lives remaining')
        print(f"The letters you already guessed are {guessed_letters}")
    def gain(self):
        self.value += 1
        # insert your own print messages if you wish.
```

Mind you I wouldn't recommend doing it for this use case (KISS principal applies), but for more complex projects where you have objects that need their own attributes and functions, Classes are great for that purpose.